# generating emails group by tuple values python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a tuple in the format (Name, email, units sold). I would like to generate an HTML table, grouped by Name and then embed that table into an email through Outlook.

My Code:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import win32com.client

mytuple = [('Andrew','Andrew@gmail.com','20'),('Jim',"Jim@gmail.com",'12'),("Sarah","Sarah@gmail.com",'43'),("Jim","Jim@gmail.com",'15'),("Andrew","Andrew@gmail.com",'56')]
mytuple = sorted(mytuple)
FULL_HTML = []

for name, rows in groupby(mytuple, itemgetter(0)):
     table = []
     for name, value2 in rows:
        table.append(
            "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(
                name, value2 ))

     html_code = "<html><table>" + str(table) + "</table></html>"

     olMailItem = 0x0
     obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
     newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
     newMail.Subject = "This is the subject"
     newMail.HTMLBody = html_code
     newMail.To  = "sampleemail@gmail.com"
     newMail.Display()
```

Desired output:

This would open 3 emails with HTML code in their body.

Email 1:

```
<html>
<table>
<tr><td>Andrew</td><td>20</td><td></tr>
<tr><td>Andrew</td><td>56</td><td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Email 2:

```
<html>
<table>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>12</td><td></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>15</td><td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Email 3:

```
<html>
<table>
<tr><td>Sarah</td><td>43</td><td></tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
for name, value2 in rows:
    table.append(
        "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(
            name, value2 ))
```

Change this to:

```
for n, e, id in rows:
    table.append(
        "<tr><td>{}</td><td>{}</td></tr>".format(
            n, id ))

html_code = "<html><table>" + ''.join(table) + "</table></html>"
```

The groupby function still returns 3-tuples.

Comment: so you always have to have all the columns in your for statement?

Comment: Yes, the 'groupby' doesn't change the structure of the iterable.